# Firebase Analytics for Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

Recently i integrated the firebase notification and migrated from GCM. Everything working well. But i want to know regarding USER-SEGMENT option in firebase console. Its totally works based on firebase analytics and captured some default user-properties and events.

Default capturing user-property :
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486

But before that the action i want to clarify below few items. Anybody knows reply those questions.

1. Different between Topic and Audience?. Where we need to integrate TOPIC and Audience?.
2. How will make the Audience via Firebase? and how will control like today particular user as a free member and captured that person into Free member in particular audience group and then he / she become a paid member, then how will remove that person from that particular audience group?.
3. Whether any possibilities monthly or day wise audiences can able to send the pushnotification via USER-SEGMENT in firebase console?.
4. User-property - Where i have to use this option in App?
5. How will do the firebase analytics for make this report like one particular member will take the action from this particular category?. ( **For example : So many members like 20000 members take the action like send a message from Search Page.** )

**Any ideas regarding these clarification.**

Comment: There are way too many questions here. Stack Overflow is not well suited for writing ad-hoc tutorials. Limit yourself to a single question to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

An audience is a group of the users of your app that share certain properties. For example, you could define an audience of all users of the Android version of your app from Holland. Then you could send a notification to that audience from the Firebase Console.

A topic is nothing more than a "thing" that the user's app can subscribe to. If you then send messages to that topic through either the Firebase Console of the Cloud Messaging API, it will be received by the apps that have subscribed to the topic.

You could say that topics are groups of users that the app code (and thus potentially the users) determine that they're a part of, while audiences are determined on the server based on app analytics.

You define audiences in the [Analytics panel of the Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/analytics/).